# SSIS Send Mail Event Handler - Hangs when using variable

Tags: sql-server, email, ssis, message

I've got a Data Flow Task that has an Event Handler for On Error, which sends me an email.

When that mail task is set to use MessageSourceType Direct Input, I can type in a string, and that string will be emailed to me.

When I create a variable with a default string value, and use that as my source, the Send Mail Task just hangs there as yellow, not sending the mail message.

I'm not even using that parameter as input or output anywhere except this mail task.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a long shot but have you tried changing the scope of the variable? does it need to have a scope of "package"?

Comment: Had the same thought and gave that a shot... but with no success.  I ended up moving the Send Mail task to the Control Flow, and that works... but I'm not putting that as an answer because it doesn't solve the issue, just avoids it.